# SQLite view as an argument for QSqlTableModel::setTable()

Tags: qt, sqlite, model-view

I want my `QTableView` connected to `QSqlTableModel`, to dynamically update itself. SQLite view that I'm going to feed to my `QSqlTableModel` will be created from a number of SQLite tables with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. the idea is to make any changes in those constituent SQLite tables automatically propagate through the SQLite view and `QSqlTableModel` into the `QTableView`.

- Is it okay to pass SQLite views to `QSqlTableModel::setTable()`?
- Will the `QSqlTableModel` and `QTableView` immediately reflect the changes in the SQLite view?
- Is there a better way to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way to achieve the goal?

as of now, i have come to the conclusion that in this case it's better to use

- an SQLite table instead of an SQLite view because it provides a faster look-up for **Q...TableModel**,
- a sublass of **QAbstractTableModel** instead of **QSqlTableModel**, so that i can update the source SQLite tables first, then **QAbstractTableModel::beginResetModel()**, rebuild the joined SQLite table, and finally **QAbstractTableModel::endResetModel()**.

Answer (score 0):

QSqlTableModel does not update itself if the underlying tables change from elsewhere (at least this does apply to MySql and i am pretty sure that QSqlTableModel is passive).

Comment: okay, do you mean the only thing that i miss here is to call QSqlTableModel::select() whenever the underlying tables change? and all the rest will work as i described above?

Comment: If i understand you right (adding a SqlLite View to QSqlTableModel, setting the model to a tableView) .. then yes. But you won't be able to change the data via the model/view because SQLite Views are read-only AFAIK.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but even if i use a SQLite table instead of a SQLite view and delete a row in my QSqlTableModel, it won't change the source tables. if so, then it's better to change the source and let the whole chain update itself, isn't it?

Comment: QSqlTableModel _can_ be used to change database fields. Just read the documentation. Deletion of a row is also possible. How and when it is done in the source table depends on the submission mode. How you do e.g. a deletion depends on the application scenario. For my needs (or client needs) i typically use a modified QSqlQueryModel and handle the change of source data by myself. But i barely have a typical "table application" - so using straight QSqlQueries is often better in my typical use-cases.